# show a confirmation box before deleting a row of the table

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I have a table whose view is something like this

```
ID  NAME  LOCATION  DELETE
1   sam   US        delete
```

I have a statement from the table that deletes the given row

```
echo "<td><a href=\"delete_members.php?id=".$row['id']."\">Delete</a></td>";
```

It redirects to delete_members.php page and the row gets deleted, however i wish to display an alert box that makes sure that the user wants to delete the row or not. for it i have a code

```
<button onclick="myFunction()">Delete</button>

<script>
function myFunction() {
    var x;
    if (confirm("Press a button!") == true) {
        window.location="yourphppage.php"; // not sure which link should be placed here
        return true;
    } else {
        window.location="index.php";
        return true;
    }
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = x;
}
</script>
```

code for the delete_members.php page

```
<?php
include('admin_session.php');
$con=mysqli_connect("abc.com","abc","abc","abc");
// Check connection
if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
}

$id = $_GET['id']; 

mysqli_query($con,"DELETE FROM members WHERE id='".$id."'");
mysqli_close($con);
header("Location: admin_member_list.php");
?>
```

However, i am unable to use the confirmation script with the statement in a proper way. i want that the alert box gets popped up(i.e the script runs) after i click on the edit button that is present on the first statement given above and then if the user confirms it should run the delete_members.php script. would appreciate if someone could guide me

Comment: So you want the user to see a confirm dialog box whenever he clicks on the link that deletes the specific row? Which `button` have you associated this `onclick` function with then?

Comment: @ Vivek Pradhan yes i wish to delete a specific row by clicking on delete (i didn't used a button i made a link) but before that a confirmation box should get displayed

Comment: does $id actually have a value? What happens if you just echo "DELETE FROM members WHERE id='".$id."'"? Also, add a die() function to check for errors: mysqli_query($con,"DELETE FROM members WHERE id='".$id."'") or die(mysqli_error($con)); AND remove the header() too, just in case you miss out on warnings or errors

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the most simple way:

```
echo "<a onclick=\"return confirm('Delete this record?')\" href=\"delete_members.php?id=".$row['id']."\">delete</a>";
```

you could also do this in an unobtrusive manner, by adding a class to the links and selecting them all at once using something like jQuery and then bind the confirmation logic to the onclick event. Something like this:

```
$('a.delete').on('click', function() {
    var choice = confirm('Do you really want to delete this record?');
    if(choice === true) {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
});
```

Comment: i tried your code but it didn' worked and has also changed the position of the delete link. it is not getting displayed where it earlier did

Comment: can you show the HTML that's rendered by PHP? Do you have an HTML validator that can check for validity of the document?

Comment: please define 'didn't work out'... Any javascript errors? Which piece of code did you use? The onclick inside the link tag should definitely work....

Comment: i used the code that you have posted, i am getting the confirmation box but the data is not getting deleted it simply redirects to other page without showing any error

Comment: What other page? Is it redirecting to the href used in the link if you confirm? Cause then it does work and you should check your PHP code in that page that actually does the deletion...

Comment: i have edited my post and now displayed the delete code also.. can you please go through it

Comment: it is still only redirecting without deleting the row

Comment: did you follow my directions in my comment directly below your question? you need to debug your PHP code to see what's going on...

Answer (score 0):

```
echo "<a href='delete_members.php?id={$row['id']}' onclick=\"return confirm('Do you really want to delete this?')\">DELETE</a>";
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this. Hope it will work for you..

Add a 'delete' class to anchor tag.

```
echo "<td><a href=\"delete_members.php?id=".$row['id']."\" class=\"delete\">Delete</a></td>";
```

Then bind delete function:

```
$('.delete').on('click', myFunction);
```

Comment: i am getting an error saying:  Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_ENCAPSED_AND_WHITESPACE

Comment: Edited my post. Now, it will not give the syntax error.

Answer (score 0):

I think this will be useful please look at this

$id=$row['id'];

If you want to pass id you can use $id or else just call function without params

```
echo "<a href='#' onclick='deletemember($id)'>Delete</a>";

<script>

    function deletemember(id)
        {
                var r = confirm("Are you sure you want to delete");
                if(r == true)
                {
                     $.ajax({
                               type:"GET",
                               url:"delete_members.php",
                               data: ({id:id}),
                               success: function(data)
                               {
                                   window.location="yourphppage.php";
                                }
                         });

                }
                else
                {
                     window.location="index.php";           
                }
    }

</script>
```

Comment: it is not deleting the row

Comment: Yes I didn't write the delete logic I just wrote confirmation message alert..ok In which page you writing the query to delete the member..send the ajax request to that page..If you don't understand tell me I will explain clearly..

Comment: I have edited my code please check with that.You need to add jquery version don't forget that